# After insert macro in MS Access

Tags: sql, email, ms-access

I would like to be able to send an e-mail to a certain set of users after a new record has been added to an MS Access table.

I have tried using the After Insert option which I thought would do the trick but apparently I'm doing something wrong in the IF statement...

Here's what I have:

```
If Not(IsNull([Nr_crt])) then
   sendemail to: name.name@domain.com
   subject: ="Test"
   body: ="test"
Endif
```

`Nr_crt` is a field in the table

Comment: what version of Access are you using? is that code VBA or ACcess Table Trigger?
if its VBA code it must be "END IF" not "endif"

Comment: I'm using 2013 and it's Access table trigger

Comment: What is `[Nr_crt]` in the scope of your Sub procedure?

Comment: Trying to figure out whether or not this field is filled in. I thought that by doing so, it would represent a new record which has been inserted. I didn't think it would matter since all the fields are mandatory

Comment: How does the system know which record in the table you're referring to?

Comment: Doesn't it take the last inserted record as the one of interest?